How do I pin apt version of Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04?
I followed the instructions on Mozilla support website:

Install Firefox .deb package for Debian-based distributions (Recommended)
To install the .deb package through the APT repository, do the following:

Create a directory to store APT repository keys if it doesn't exist:
sudo install -d -m 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings


Import the Mozilla APT repository signing key:
wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O- | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc > /dev/null
If you do not have wget installed, you can install it with: sudo apt-get install wget

The fingerprint should be 35BAA0B33E9EB396F59CA838C0BA5CE6DC6315A3. You may check it with the following command:
gpg -n -q --import --import-options import-show /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc | awk '/pub/{getline; gsub(/^ +| +$/,""); if($0 == "35BAA0B33E9EB396F59CA838C0BA5CE6DC6315A3") print "\nThe key fingerprint matches ("$0").\n"; else print "\nVerification failed: the fingerprint ("$0") does not match the expected one.\n"}'

Next, add the Mozilla APT repository to your sources list:
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list > /dev/null

Configure APT to prioritize packages from the Mozilla repository:
echo '
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1000
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla


Update your package list, and install the Firefox .deb package:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox




So now I have:
$ apt list --installed | grep firefox
firefox/mozilla,now 132.0~build1 amd64 [installed]

$ snap list | grep firefox
firefox                    131.0.2-1                    5091   latest/stable
mozilla**         -

I don't mind having both apt and snap versions installed on my system. The problem is the apt version gets uninstalled when a software update is done even though the "Configure APT to prioritize packages from the Mozilla repository" step was done.
How do I stop the apt version being uninstalled and replaced by snap from software updates?

Try simultaneously lowering the priority of the Ubuntu package.
echo '
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla


Your answer is correct, and is also now tested! (before Nov 26 ) snap list | grep firefox >> 132.0.1-2 And snap find firefox | grep mozilla >> 132.0.2-2
